# Elasticsearch update a new mapping on index with default values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am updating by my index with new properties in Elasticsearch and trying to add default vales for new created properties, i have tried the below approach , but the update query is failing with the following error message 'failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [summaryTableColumns] is not of nested type

**New Mapping**

```
{
  "properties": {
    "subjectPropertyFields": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "summaryTableColumns": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "key": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update query using painless that i have tried**

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.summaryTableColumns=  params.summaryTableColumns",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "summaryTableColumns": [
        {
          "key": "Property Name",
          "value": "name"
        },
        {
          "key": "City",
          "value": "city"
        },
        {
          "key": "Distance",
          "value": "propertyAddress"
        },
        {
          "key": "Units",
          "value": "units"
        },
        {
          "key": "Built",
          "value": "yearBuilt"
        },
        {
          "key": "Occupancy",
          "value": "occupancyAsOfDate"
        },
        {
          "key": "Avg SF",
          "value": "avgSf"
        },
        {
          "key": "Avg Rent",
          "value": "avgMarketRentSf"
        },
        {
          "key": "Avg Rent/SF",
          "value": "avgRentSf"
        },
        {
          "key": "NA",
          "value": "NA"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "summaryTableColumns",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "summaryTableColumns"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "match": {
              "templateName": "salesComps"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**error i am facing**
'failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [summaryTableColumns] is not of nested type

Comment: Can you show how your current mapping looks like?

Comment: {
  "settings": {
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 4000,
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "mapId": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "templateName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Can you show which endpoint you're hitting exactly, because `failed to create query` is a bit weird when trying to update a mapping. Are you hitting `_search` instead of `_mapping`?